# How can I delete a row on fetch reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, fetch

this is the part where i the table from the api

```
renderItem(d, i) {
      return <tr key={i} >
      <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
            <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
            <td>{d.Address }</td> 
            <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
            <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this, d.Employee_ID)} >Delete</button></center></td>
     </tr>
    }

    handleOnclick(id,name,address) {
      debugger

     this.setState({
        Employee_Name: name,
        Address: address,
      });
      }
    }
```

So i tried using this on deleting a row however im not sure where or how did i got wrong please help i really don't know how

```
  onDelete(id) {
        deleteEmployeet(id)
             .then((data) => {
              let  jsonReturnedValue = this.state.Employee_Name.filter((post) => {
                return id !== post.id;
                    });

                    this.setState(state => {
                        state.Employee_Nam = Employee_Nam;
                        return state;
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error('err', err);
                });
        }
    export function deleteBlogPost(id) {
        return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetails/' + id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            mode: 'CORS'
        }).then(res => res)
        }).catch(err => err);
    }
```

this is where i render it a place where i render my code on reactjs

```
render() {

  let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;

return(
  <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
          <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
           <table className= "table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
                  {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: where do you call `renderItem(...)`? can you post that code?

Comment: ohh its on the modal

Comment: Where did you trigger the "onDelete" function (after being deleted, the list should be re-rendered, seems fine since you're using "setState", but not sure about when and how you trigger the delete function)? I got confused between your "deleteEmployee" and "onDelete" functions

Comment: im not really sorry im very confused this is my first time doing this

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confused ^^, but now please try removing your `onDelete()`, `deleteEmployeet()` and `export function deleteBlogPost(id)`, calm down and use my idea instead:

```
// ...
handleOnclick(id,name,address) {}

//same level as the above `handleOnclick()` function
deleteEmployee(id) {
        return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetails/' + id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            mode: 'CORS'
        })then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log("the list after deleting...", resp);
          // Please use `this.setState()` with the above "resp" here to reset your employee list, 
          // I think it's gonna be the same just like when you render your employee for the first time
        });

}
```

Since this is the way you should do, it it doesn't work yet, please tell me the errors you get, but this approaching should be correct, thanks!

Comment: hmmm how about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972336/how-can-i-delete-a-row-on-fetch-by-onclick-in-reactjs can you might help me on this part

Comment: hey are you busy...? im still confused im still stuck with this please help me what do you mean set state? how

Comment: Really, still not solved this yet, how about showing me some errors on your log now, thanks ?

Comment: hmm i think im having conflict on my web configs it says  [link] (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))  so im very lost now i put the delete on verbs and access-controll... i dont know now i cant do any delete without fixing my api's web config

Comment: Actually, returning 404 (Not Found) means your API has problem itself. Could you double check that "'http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetails/' + id" works fine, and also check that this API works well with CORS, too (may require some settings on the server). After the server-side is fine, we will consider the client-side (which is your current react's components) ^^

Comment: im confuse i never heard of cors fufufu what is it how can i check it there? ,but i tried to work it with postman it was working ..

Comment: CORS is not so weird, you can easily find some writing about it out there. However, if using postman is find, stick with it and move on. You can send me your current state of code, and also some errors, too ^^ ! I will try to help if I can

Comment: hmmm where can i send it? im sorry im still learning im confused about everything..

Comment: i commented the whole code i hope you can help me please im working on this since yesterday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144402/discussion-between-thinhvo0108-and-patricia-mari-maclang).

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import form from './add.jsx';

export default class employee extends React.Component {


constructor() {

    super();
      this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [],
         Employee_Name: '',
         Employee_ID: '',
         Address: '',
       }

         }


componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()})
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json});
  });
}


renderItem(d, i) {
  return <tr key={i} >
  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address }</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.department)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}>Delete</button></center></td>
 </tr>
}

handleOnclick(id,name,address,department) {


 this.setState({
    Employee_Name: name,
    Address: address,
    Department: department,
  });
  }

deleteEmployee(id) {

   jQuery.support.cors = true;
    debugger
      fetch ('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id,
      { method: 'DELETE',
        credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then( 
          res =>  {
              this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json})
              var employee = [...this.state.employee];
              var idx = employee.findIndex(item => item.Employee_ID === id);
              employee.splice(idx, 1);
              this.setState({employee})

         }
      )
      .catch( err => console.error(err))
  }  

render() {

  let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;

return(
  <div>
      <div className="container">

        <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
          <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
           <table className= "table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
                  {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

    {/*Updating*/}

<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" 
                       value={this.state.Employee_Name} 
                       name="Employee_Name"
                       /> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.Address} 
                       name="Address"
                       />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.Address} 
                       name="Address"
                       />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    {/*Adding*/}
      <div className="modal fade" id="AddEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Add New Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       name={this.props.Employee_Name}
                       className="EmployeeDetails"
                       value={this.props.value}
                       onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="text"
                       name={this.props.address}
                       className="EmployeeDetails"
                       value={this.props.value}
                       onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Department</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="text"
                       name={this.props.address}
                       className="EmployeeDetails"
                       value={this.props.value}
                       onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info" onClick = {this.save}> Add Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
    );

}

}
```