# How can i delete a row on fetch by onclick in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am very new to this i dont know how to delete a row by  using fetch.. ive already made a messed up code i don't know how it will work now please help me im so lost...

```
renderItem(d, i) {
      return <tr key={i} >
      <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
            <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
            <td>{d.Address }</td> 
            <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
            <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}>Delete</button></center></td>
     </tr>
    }

    handleOnclick(id,name,address) {


     this.setState({
        Employee_Name: name,
        Address: address,
      });
      }

    deleteEmployee(id) {
        debugger
          fetch ('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetail/'+ id,
          { method: 'DELETE',})
          .then( 
              res =>  this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json})
          )
          .catch( err => cosole.error(err))                
      }
```

Comment: @thinhvo0108 hmm can you help me maybe?

Comment: Where are you facing the problem, is it delete and then rerender is not happening or its not deleting in the backend as well. Isee that your renderItem has only one row, are you mapping and calling this function. How does it work, can you give more details

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri im good with the rendering part my problem was deleting i cant delete a row when clicking a button

Comment: You did not understand my question, When you click delete button, is your fetch call giving you an error, then can you add the code for api, `api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetail` or if fetch call is returning properly then you need to update it in your state

Comment: it's working on api when i link that but not on react...

Comment: one last question, which state variable are you using to render table and how is its structure

Answer (score 0):

After deleting your element from api you also need to remove it from your state, Suppose you are rendering your table from state `employee`. then you need to do

```
deleteEmployee(id) {
    debugger
      fetch ('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/deleteemployeedetail/'+ id,
      { method: 'DELETE',})
      .then( 
          res =>  {
              this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json})
              var employee = [...this.state.employee];
              var idx = employee.findIndex(item => item.Employee_ID === id);
              employee.splice(idx, 1);
              this.setState({employee})

         }
      )
      .catch( err => cosole.error(err))                
  }
```

Comment: it kinda works but it says :5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/18 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: its not your fault tho im just lost i dont know what im doing -_- :/

Comment: Can you make sure that your delete-api works well ^^ ? Ah next time, when you type @thinhvo0108, I cannot receive if I am not in the discussion yet, so ping me by another way, thanks

Comment: You can ask a separate question maybe for your API if it still doesn't work. Also could you accept this as an answer if it helped